# Can't apply the patch

Tags: patch

I have unpacked the source code of **efivar-0.23.tar.gz** and trying to apply the following patch: http://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/117073/ to be able to compile it.

I have entered the unpacked directory, and issued the following command: `patch -Np1 ../efivar.patch`, but nothing is happening. It just waits (*like it is doing something, but nothing is happening*).

How is it possible to apply this patch? I was looking through different articles on the net, but the result seems to be the same..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `patch` command expects the Patch at `stdin`. So either pipe the patch into the command:

```
patch -Np1 < ../efivar.patch
```

or specify the input file with the `-i` argument.

```
patch -Np1 -i ../efivar.patch
```

As you can see, the first diff is from file `a/meta-oe/recipes-extended/efivar/efivar/0001-efivar-fix-for-cross-compile.patch`. 
Let's assume the actual relativ-file path is `efivar/0001-efivar-fix-for-cross-compile.patch` from your current working directory. Then you have to tell `patch` to ignore the first 4 directory levels, so it can find the files to patch. You do this by saying `p4` instead of `p1`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since the patch in question was created with Git, you could use
Git to apply it:

```
curl patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/117073/mbox/ | git am
```

Or:

```
curl patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/117073/raw/ | git apply
```

[How do patches work in Git?](//stackoverflow.com/a/9256253)